Do GPUs perform instruction pipelining?
I usually write and optimize code to be run on the CPU, however I'm currently trying to write shaders for light scattering.
I know CPUs have certain optimizations in order to try to get as close to 1 instruction per cycle as possible: instruction pipelining, branch prediction, etc.
However, I don't know much about how GPU cores handle this. From what I've read, they tend not to do branch 'prediction' per se, and so I wonder if they pipeline instructions?
Whether they do this might impact how I split up an algorithm, as I can have multiple independent calculations with more net operations, or one sequential, data-dependent calculation with fewer overall operations.

GPU's (for the most part) don't do branch prediction.  They use warps.  Both paths of execution are executed, so in general, avoid divergent branches (e.g. if statements).  You should probably be optimizing for access to memory.  As with all things related to optimization, the devil is in the details.  Depending on the application, even general strategies may not result in optimal performance.  Which platform and runtime are you on and what, specifically, are you trying to optimize?

Just looking for a general rule of thumb, as it's a GLSL shader for game development, and the platform isn't really known.
As far as I know, the algorithm in question isn't memory-bound, since there's only a couple input variables fed into a few stages of processing, with a finalizer function at the end working on all the calculated values

Different vendors can do different things with GPUs, and some don't divulge hardware-level optimizations easily, so this answer is just my best understanding of the situation.
In general, GPUs process large numbers of things (vertices, fragments, you name it) in parallel.  They can do so in batches, for example 64 or more verts in a batch all execute at the same time.  But each vertex does not get its own execution engine, so you can't have 64 different lines of code active all at the same time.  Instead, all in a batch must share one execution engine, and a single shader instruction affects all batch members at the same time, in parallel.
In this scenario, a batch of vertices are executing simultaneously, in lock-step.  There's only one "execution pointer" if you will, one line of shader source code, and all verts in the batch are on that same line together, just with different values in their variables (because each single variable from source is actually an array as large as the batch!)
But now the batch encounters an "if" statement with an "else" clause.  Only some members of the batch can take the top half.  The ones that fail the "if" statement become inactive, executing no-op for each instruction, waiting while the active ones work through their code.  When the batch reaches the "else" clause, the active ones become inactive and vice-versa, and the whole batch steps through the else clause, with only some of the batch executing that code while the originally-active ones execute no-ops along the way.  When the if / else clause ends, all members of the batch become active again and resume executing instructions in lock-step with each other.
So generally, you don't want to have special cases where only a small percentage of (vertices / fragments / whatever) members of your batches wind up with special case scenarios that require a lot of extra computation.  This will bring down performance across the board.
Ideally, you want all batch members to do about the same amount of work, for best performance.

Thanks for the insight! I was mostly asking about pipelining but I ended up learning my understanding of branching wasn't very good lol
